# Cypher Query: How to Save a Cypher Query inside Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to save a cypher query inside a cypher query. But have been unable to.
The goal of my app is to allow to save a cypher query and query the cypher queries in neo4j, and then be able to add values inside them.

```
Example 
create (q:Query{QID:'1',Query:'Create (u:User{Type:'{{Programmer}}'})'}) return q
```

How can I write the cypher query correcty? As well as change the values with parameters? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps user :Programmer as a label too

Comment: And use parameters, like {type} and parameters: {"type":"Programmer"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes for your statement you want to save:

```
create (q:Query{QID:'1',Query:"Create (u:User{Type:'{{Programmer}}'})"}) return q
```